# PDO restore from bak SQL Server returns false when fetch PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to get compatibility level of a `.bak` file. I'm doing this to get it:

```
$connection = new PDO("dblib:host=".$this->server.";dbname=".$this->dbname, $this->user, $this->password);
$stmt = $connection->prepare('DECLARE @Bakpath varchar(500)
        SET @Bakpath = :path
        restore HEADERONLY from disk=@Bakpath');

$res = $stmt->execute(array('path' => 'C:\\datacaptures\\0003_0141_dataCapture.bak'));
```

`$connection` is a PDO object.

When I fetch the result, it returns `false`.

Can somebody help me? Using the same portion of code with a normal `SELECT` in any table works fine.

Thanks

Comment: `setQuery()` doesn't appear to be a PDO method, so what is $connection really.

Comment: Sorry, it was a method of a custom Class. I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you add some error info: `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: `errorInfo();` prints something like this:

    `Array
    (
        [0] => 00000
        [1] => 0
        [2] => (null) [0] (severity 0) [(null)]
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
    )`

Using mssql native functions returns the array that I want:

`Array
(
    [BackupName] => DataCapture backup
    [BackupDescription] => 
    [BackupType] => 1
    [ExpirationDate] => 
    [Compressed] => 0
    [Position] => 1
    [DeviceType] => 2
    [UserName] => sa
    [ServerName] => MEX0322SL
    [DatabaseName] => DataCapture
    [DatabaseVersion] => 539
    ...`

Comment: I've added the PDO connection